# Is it possible to create "double a" in V8?

Tags: v8

Let I have `Local<Integer> a = Integer:: New(3)` 
But I need: a = 3.5 - so, I have to use double type. However, there are no double type in V8, as I understand. 
Are there any other ways for  creating a = 3.5 using V8? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double precision floats are the default (and actually only) number type in JavaScript. So:

```
Local<Number> x = Number::New(isolate, 3.5);
```